# Error when clicking on an item of a listview

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am developing an application which makes a mysq queries and returns data, I explain better, I have the first screen where a name eg income and sent for Peter on the basis that if found returns the name and last name and that shows on screen wil another in a listview so far so good, the problem is that when I click on this name should show another screen and this should also show all the data of this person is should show surname cedula, etc ... but q passes clicking gives me an error this is the error that I get the logcat

```
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNe twork(StrictMode.java:1117)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java: 84)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127 )
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.j ava:192)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.j ava:459)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.con nectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionO perator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOper ator.java:144)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(A bstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapte r.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector .execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.exe cute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.exe cute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.exe cute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at com.example.taller06oct.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest (JSONParser.java:62)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at com.example.taller06oct.EditEmpleadosActivity$GetE mpleadoDetails$1.run(EditEmpleadosActivity.java:13 4)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725 )
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92 )
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.jav a:5039)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCa ller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit .java:560)
01-17 16:03:49.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I was reviewing and apparently the problem is in the conversion q json but as I said I am new to java and android do not understand how to fix it, I leave my Java code, by the way I'm using AsyncTask will mention  ...

```
try {
// Building Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cedula", cedula));
Log.i("1","busca empleado para cargar detalles");
// getting Empleado details by making HTTP request
// Note that Empleado details url will use GET request
**JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
url_detalles_empleado, "GET", params);**
Log.i("1","llama a php busqueda");

// check your log for json response
Log.d("Single Empleado Details", json.toString());

// json success tag
success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

Thanks in advance, I hope your help thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

You can't do network operations in the main thread.

Checkout AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

For painless threading.